# Why does soft keyboard show up?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to find out why the soft keyboard show up in one of my views ?

The app is quite big and it's not obvious why the keyboard gets enabled. Do you know any way to debug that?

Comment: Can you provide at least the xml of the layout?

Comment: well, it's a legacy app, with a complex system of nested controller patterns...i can't easily isolate the issue

Comment: Have you tried my suggested answer? It's almost impossible to help without further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line of code in the activity's onCreate method to make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

In the manifest.

Comment: That actually works, but I still could not figure out why the keyboard appeared

Comment: It depends on what elements you have in your UI and what has focus on launch.